# Yii Api Version urlManager w/ parseUrl

Tags: php, yii

Im new with Yii and Im trying to implement the parseUrl to manage API Version at the url.
I would like to redirect /api/1.0/... to controller apiV1.0.

Main.php (urlManager rules):

```
...
array('class' => 'application.components.ApiVersion'),
...
```

ApiVersion.php:

```
<?php
    class ApiVersion extends CBaseUrlRule
    {
    public $connectionID = 'db';

    public function createUrl($manager,$route,$params,$ampersand)
    {
        if ($route==='car/index')
        {
            if (isset($params['manufacturer'], $params['model']))
                return $params['manufacturer'] . '/' . $params['model'];
            else if (isset($params['manufacturer']))
                return $params['manufacturer'];
        }
        return false;  // this rule does not apply
    }

    public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo)
    {
        if (preg_match('%^(\w+)(/(\w+))?$%', $pathInfo, $matches))
           $url =  $match[1] .  $match[2]; // BUILD YOUR URL (controllerName/actionName)
           $this->redirect(array($url));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Im very lost with how it works, someone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function the regex checks if the path is something like "api/num_of_version/your_model/an_id"

So if your url is matching this your are in the condition, you'll have to set the get values:

```
$_GET['apiversion'] = $matches[2];
$_GET['model'] = $matches[4];
$_GET['id'] = $matches[6];
```

And depending on the version you return the good controller:

```
return "apiV" . $_GET['apiversion'] . "/view";
```

Some links you need to understand:

- [How preg_match works (what is the structure of $matches)](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php)
- [Yii custom Url class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes)

Edit: If there is a particular point where your have some trouble please let me now, i'll try to ellaborate a little more my answer on this point.

Comment: Hi darkheir. It still not working, what I should right in function createUrl?

Comment: In your edit both the createUrl  and the parseUrl are not adapted to what you need to do! U just took the ones from the documentation!

Comment: But it is because I do not know how. I need to have the function createUrl?

Comment: parseUrl is when Yii is trying to resolve the url entered by the user (or from a ling). createUrl is when in your code you are using $this->createUrl($route,$params); You use it if you want to have a custom url in your adress.
I think in your case you'll only need parseUrl!

Comment: Then you also need to know how to create a regular expression that'll match your need (ie: /api/1.0/...)